# How to load variable from one PowerShell script to another?

Tags: powershell

I have a main script that is calling on several others scripts and I need to load the variables from the other scripts into the main script so that I can dump them into a html file. I tried dot sourcing the scripts I am calling on but that did not work or I am doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Example section of script:

```
.\get-cluster.ps1

$MyReport += Get-CustomHeader "Clusters not in compliance : $($CapacityInfo.count) ($MyReport += Get-HTMLTable $capacityinfo
$MyReport += Get-CustomHeaderClose
```

The variable `$capacityinfo` exists in the `get-cluster.ps1` script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your get-cluster.ps1 file is in your root dir, dot source would look more like this:

```
. .\Get-Cluster.ps1
```

This will execute the Get-Cluster.ps1 script in the same scope as the caller making its script level variables available in the caller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My script was not in the root dir so I was not calling it probably. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Dot sourcing will accomplish your goal. However, this is an ambiguous design and conflicts with the PowerShell CmdLet Development Guidelines. Granted you are authoring a script and not a Cmdlet but it appears you're trying to follow PowerShell conventions given the script file name you have chosen.

Using the verb `Get` implies that you are retrieving a resource. So if you have a script called `Get-Cluster.ps1` then it should retrieve one or more `Cluster` instances. Consider the following instead:

```
$clusters = .\Get-Cluster.ps1 -NonCompliantOnly
```

This will still enable you to set a variable in your current scope without all the magic and ambiguity of dot sourcing. I'm not trying to be preachy but the PowerShell team has done a good job creating creating consistency and I think there is a lot of value in attempting to perpetuate that when we extend PowerShell with our own scripts/modules/cmdlets. If you're dead set on setting a new or existing variable in the current scope using dot sourcing then I'd encourage you to find a new verb.

See [Approved Cmdlet Verbs on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-5.1) for more info.