# Can I make a function acessable that was dot-sourced within an imported-module to the parent script?

Tags: .net, powershell

I have imported module "ModuleFoo.psm1" to my script: "ModuleBar.ps1"

And I call a method which is in the imported module that does dot sourcing to function BarFunction.ps1:

```
function Dot-SourceBarFunction()
{
. "\BarFunction.ps1"
}
```

Can I make this BarFunction.ps1 accessible from the parent scope that is : ModuleBar.ps1?

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136654/how-to-load-variable-from-one-powershell-script-to-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should just work e.g.:

```
-- Outer.ps1 --
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\module.psm1
Get-Foo


-- Module.psm1 --
. $PSScriptRoot\inner.ps1


-- Inner.ps1 --
function Get-Foo {
    "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name) called"
}
```

This outputs `Get-Foo called`.  Functions default to public visibility in modules so when you dot-source the script that pulls in functions within a module, those are automatically made public.